# Set age limit with UIDatePicker, Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to set the age limit, when I select the date of birth if the age is less than 18, then I print an error

```
 @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy"

        dateBirthday.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateBirthday.text!) {
            let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date, to: Date()).year!
            print(age)  //
            self.age.text = "You are \(age) age"
            `continue`.isEnabled = true
        } else {

            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateBirthday.text!)
            let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date!, to: Date()).year!
            print(age)
          if age < 18 {

                self.age.text = "Error you are \(age)"
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? You should get the date/age anyway, and then apply the if/else (<18) code.

Comment: when the age is less than 18, the error does not come out

Comment: Think: You wrote an `if let/else` test. Where does your code? Does it pass the if let? Why should it pass it, or why it shouldn't. Then read the second line of my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateBirthday.text!) {
        let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date, to: Date()).year!

        if age >= 18 {
            print(age)
            self.age.text = "You are \(age) age"
            continue.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            self.age.text = "Error you are \(age)"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your date and age formatter out of your if statements. Usually, if you have the same code in both branches of an if statement it can be pulled before or after the code.

```
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateBirthday.text!) {
    let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date!, to: Date()).year!
    print(age)

    if age < 18 {
       self.age.text = "Error you are \(age)"
    } else {
       self.age.text = "You are \(age) age"
       `continue`.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I see @rbaldwin and I came up with pretty much the same answer...

Comment: Except your < is the wrong way round ;)

Comment: Ha!! Right, corrected. Good catch.

Comment: It needs to be `>= 18`.  `>18` means 18 will fall through to the error statement.   The OP wants to filter less than 18. :)

Comment: I think he can figure that out, but you are correct. ;) But I'm just going to reverse the check.